# How to run query for getting data from different table if result is different

Tags: mysql

Hope someone can help me to get data from query

I have 5 table

1. Log Activities

   |id   |user |activity_id |content_id|
   |1    |1    |1           |1         |
   |2    |1    |2           |1         |
   |3    |1    |3           |1         |
   |4    |2    |1           |2         |
   |5    |2    |2           |2         |
   |6    |2    |3           |2         |
   |7    |2    |1           |3         |
   |8    |3    |2           |3         |
   |9    |3    |3           |3         |
   |10   |3    |1           |1         |

2 Table Activity
    |id   |name_activity |
    |1    |VIEW          |
    |2    |CLICK BUTTON  |
    |3    |PLAY VIDEO    |

3. Table Users
   |id   |name      |
   |1    |Alex      |
   |2    |Andrian   |
   |3    |Arthur    |
4. Table Pages (if activity_id=1)
   |id   |name      |
   |1    |HOME      |
   |2    |CONTACT   |
   |3    |PROFILE   |
5. Table Button (if activity_id=2)
   |id   |name      |
   |1    |Read More |
   |2    |Submit    |
   |3    |Register  |

How to get query to show log activity join to user, activity, and content_id base from activity_id
    |id   |nuser_name |activity_id   |content_id|
    |1    |Alex       |VIEW          |HOME         |
    |2    |Alex       |CLICK BUTTON  |Read More    |
    |3    |Alex       |PLAY VIDEO    |AnotherTable1|
    |4    |Andrian    |VIEW          |CONTACT      |
    |5    |Andrian    |CLICK BUTTON  |Submit       |
    |6    |Andrian    |PLAY VIDEO    |AnotherTable2|
    |7    |Andrian    |VIEW          |AnotherTable3|
    |8    |Arthur     |CLICK BUTTON  |Register     |
    |9    |Arthur     |PLAY VIDEO    |AnotherTable3|
    |10   |Arthur     |VIEW          |HOME         |

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN`, e.g:

```
SELECT la.id, u.name, a.name_activity, IF(a.id = 1, p.name, b.name) As content_id
FROM log_activities la LEFT JOIN users u ON la.user = u.id
LEFT JOIN activity a ON la.activity_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN pages p ON la.content_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN button b ON la.content_id = b.id;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
But what I need is to show content_id base on activity_id, let's say if activity_id is 1, you are left join from table Pages, but if activity_id is 2 you are using table Button

Comment: Thank you Darshan,
It's very helpfull
Once again can you give me example if we have another table? which code must I put "IF"?

Comment: If you have another table then (a) you need to include it in `JOIN` and (b) you need to write an `IF` condition on whichever column you want to render differently.
Also, please mark the answer as accepted if it has helped you.